# Calculating columns vertically

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are trying to do an analysis of how long our staff have been working on a hourly basis for trending and forecasting purposes.

I want to do a headcount by calculating all the values in the columns vertically.

This is the outputs in SQL in hourly format
(I have circled the values I want to sum up)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJbWi.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM3YV.png]

As long as the value is more than 0, I want to count it as 1 as this is for headcount by hour.

This is part of my query to produce the output.

```
    SELECT 

--b.*,
b.EMPLOYEENAME,
B.DEPARTMENT,

CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(b.SHIFTA_start,17),103) AS SHIFTA_start,
CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(b.ShiftA_End,17),103) as ShiftA_End,
b.StartTime_HOUR,
b.StartTime_min,
b.EndTime_HOUR,
b.EndTime_min,


CASE WHEN b.[0H_START] < b.[0H_END] THEN  b.[0H_START] ELSE b.[0H_END] END AS [0],
CASE WHEN b.[1H_START] < b.[1H_END] THEN  b.[1H_START] ELSE b.[1H_END] END AS [1]


from
(
/*Step 2  - calculating minutes from starttime and endtime */

select a.*,

/**Calculating the number of minutes worked from start_time MIN **/
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 0 and a.[0] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[0] END AS [0H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 1 and a.[1] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[1] END AS [1H_START],


/**Calculating the number of minutes worked from END_time MIN **/
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 0 and a.[0] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[0] END AS [0H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 1 and a.[1] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[1] END AS [1H_END]
from

(--Step 1:
/*to determine 1 or 0 using the start and end hour 
If time falls in the respective hour = 1
if time doesnt fall in the respective hours = 0*/
SELECT 

[EMPLOYEENAME], 
[DEPARTMENT],
[SHIFTA_start],
CASE WHEN  [SHIFTA_START] !='' OR SHIFTA_START != NULL THEN CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103) ELSE NULL END AS SHIFTA_START_con,
CASE WHEN  [SHIFTA_START] !='' OR SHIFTA_START != NULL THEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS StartTime_HOUR,
CASE WHEN  [SHIFTA_START] !='' OR SHIFTA_START != NULL THEN DATEPART(mi,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS StartTime_min,

[SHIFTA_end],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_END] !='' OR SHIFTA_end != NULL THEN CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_END],17),103) ELSE NULL END AS SHIFTA_END_con,
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_END] !='' OR SHIFTA_end != NULL THEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS EndTime_HOUR,
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_END] !='' OR SHIFTA_end != NULL THEN DATEPART(mi,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS EndTime_min,


CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 0 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [0],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 1 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [1]

from [DatabaseTable].[dbo].[ATTENDANCE]

where ShiftA_Start != '' and ShiftA_End !='' and shiftA_start != shiftA_End

)a

)b
```

Please help, thank you v much!

Comment: Post sample data as text, not as images and provide query what you have tried.

Comment: What do you mean by post data as text? Do you mean in excel format?
I have already posted the query, please take a look. 
@StanislovasKalašnikovas

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the number of all values in this column you can go simply with:

```
SELECT COUNT(T.[22]) FROM Table AS T
WHERE T.[22] > 0
```

Comment: I want to calculate it individually in a vertical way of each columns.